# error in assigning a const character to an unsigned char array in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long int WORD;  /* Should be 32-bit = 4 bytes        */
#define w         32             /* word size in bits                 */
#define r         12             /* number of rounds                  */
#define b         16             /* number of bytes in key            */
#define c          4             /* number words in key               */
                                 /* c = max(1,ceil(8*b/w))            */
#define t         26             /* size of table S = 2*(r+1) words   */
WORD S [t],L[c];                        /* expanded key table         */
WORD P = 0xb7e15163, Q = 0x9e3779b9;    /* magic constants            */
/* Rotation operators. x must be unsigned, to get logical right shift*/
#define ROTL(x,y) (((x)<<(y&(w-1))) | ((x)>>(w-(y&(w-1)))))
#define ROTR(x,y) (((x)>>(y&(w-1))) | ((x)<<(w-(y&(w-1)))))    

void RC5_DECRYPT(WORD *ct, WORD *pt) /* 2 WORD input ct/output pt     */
{
    WORD i, B = ct[1], A = ct[0];
    for (i = r; i > 0; i--)
    {
        B = ROTR(B - S[2 * i + 1], A)^A;
        A = ROTR(A - S[2 * i], B)^B;
    }
    pt[1] = B - S[1]; pt[0] = A - S[0];
}

void RC5_SETUP(unsigned char *K) /* secret input key K 0...b-1]       */
{
    WORD i, j, k, u = w/8, A, B, L[c];

    /* Initialize L, then S, then mix key into S */
    for (i = b - 1, L[c - 1] = 0; i != -1; i--) 
        L[i/u] = (L[i/u] << 8) + K[i];

    for (S[0] = P, i = 1; i < t; i++) 
        S[i] = S[i - 1] + Q;

    for (A=B=i=j=k=0; k<3*t; k++,i=(i+1)%t,j=(j+1)%c)      /* 3*t > 3*c */
    {
        A = S[i] = ROTL(S [i]+(A+B),3);
        B = L[j] = ROTL(L[j]+(A+B),(A+B));
    }
}

void printword(WORD A)
{
    WORD k;
    for (k=0 ;k<w; k+=8) 
        printf("%02.2lX",(A>>k)&0xFF);
}

int main()
{ 
    WORD i, j, k, pt [2], pt2 [2], ct [2] = {0,0};
    unsigned char key[b];
    ofstream out("cpt.txt");
    ifstream in("key.txt");

    if (!in)
    { 
        cout << "Cannot open file.\n"; 
        return 1; 
    }  

    if (!out)
    { 
        cout << "Cannot open file.\n"; 
        return 1; 
    }  

    key="111111000001111";

    RC5_SETUP(key);
    ct[0]=2185970173;
    ct[1]=3384368406;

    for (i=1; i<2; i++)
    {
         RC5_DECRYPT(ct,pt2);
         printf("\n   plaintext "); 
         printword(pt[0]); 
         printword(pt[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code i get two warnings and also an error saying that I cant assign a char value to my character array. Why is that?

Comment: I love this comment /* magic constants             */

Comment: He's obviously copied this code from elsewhere and is trying to modify it, without really understanding it. No shame in that, either.

Comment: This code is a cut-n-paste (or pretty dang close) to what was published in the original RC5 description by Ron Rivest (see the Appendix of "The RC5 Encryption Algorithm" paper: http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rivest-rc5rev.pdf). I think Rivest might be described as a mathematician rather than an engineer.

Comment: @Michael Neither mathematicians nor engineers can program, in my somewhat extensive experience with both, though never with as some one as well-known as Rivest. Still, I think I would have told him to get a clue.

Comment: @Neil, in my experience, mathematicians, engineers and physicists often make far superior developers and architects as they tend to (but not always) understand the problems at hand better than a comp scientist. They tend to have better inherent design and analysis skills than a CS specialist. I've also observed better reach-out to standard libraries than immediately suffering from NIHS. In fact, one of the best programmers I've ever known came from a philosophy background. The above code aside, your blanket statement is rather bigoted and unjustified in this context.

Comment: Also, @Neil, I upvoted your very first comment. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

`key="111111000001111";`

to

`strncpy((char *)key, "111111000001111", sizeof(key));`

Comment: still the error remains .. now the error is 
rcdec.cpp:66: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’
rcdec.cpp:66: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’

Comment: @mekasperasky: OK - it sounds like you're compiling with fairly strict options - solution edited above to take this into account and also to avoid an overrun of the `key` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the value of the `key` array using a statement like:

```
key = "111111000001111";
```

You'll need to use `strcpy()`, or `memcpy()`, or something like (the non-standard, but arguably less error prone) `strlcpy()`.

However, you *can* initialize it like so:

```
unsigned char key[b] = "111111000001111";
```

But note that as long as the string is one character less than the dimension you'll get a null terminated string, but if the number of characters is equal to the dimension you'll get an array of characters that is *not* null terminated, without an error (though you might get a warning).  In C++ that scenario should generate an error. See [Why doesn't the compiler detect out-of-bounds in string constant initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675477/why-doesnt-the-compiler-detect-out-of-bounds-in-string-constant-initialization/1676325#1676325) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Because `key = "111111000001111";` is not valid in any way.  You cannot assign values to an array this way in either C or C++.  Try using `strcpy` or `memcpy` with the appropriate casts.