# How to initialize char arrays for a struct outside using strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to make a function that auto populates data into a binary file if the file does not exist. Since it doesn't exist, I want to add data myself from a function so it can also create the file itself with the data.

The struct I made

```
struct Address {
    char city[ADDR_SIZE];
    char state[ADDR_SIZE];
    int zipcode;
};
struct Record {
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int socialSecurityNum;
    int dateOfBirth;
    Address address;
};
```

I'm trying to add the data like this

```
dataFile.seekp(getBytePosition(0), ios::beg);
citizen.name = "Some name"; //ERROR: char[30] not assignable
citizen.socialSecurityNum = 123123123;
citizen.address.zipcode = 75042;
dataFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&citizen), sizeof(citizen));
```

Giving it integers is simple, but how do I make it populate the char name array?

I also tried these but failed

```
citizen.name[NAME_SIZE] = "Some name"; //Fails
citizen.name[NAME_SIZE] = {"Some Name"}; //Fails
citizen.name[NAME_SIZE] = 'Some Name'; //Too Many errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First option (not recommended)**: Use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

```
strcpy(citizen.name, "Some name");
```

or the more safer (**recomended**) [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)

```
strncpy(citizen.name, "Some name", sizeof(citizen.name));
```

**Second option (recomended)**: Instead of `char` array use a `std::string`:

```
struct Address {
    std::string city;
    std::string state;
    int zipcode;
};
struct Record {
    std::string name;
    int socialSecurityNum;
    int dateOfBirth;
    Address address;
};
```

With `std::string` you can assign to it:

```
citizen.name = "Some name";
```

However you'll have the additional burden of serializing your data but I believe it worths it.

Comment: What's wrong with strcpy? If I remember, I did try them as strings first, but then I had to use cin.getline to write to a binary file and I believe I was getting errors. I've come a long way since and it would take a while to switch it all back to string.

Comment: @Jozemite:Apps: `strcpy()` does not perform bounds checking so can cause buffer overflows if used incorrectly. Use `strncpy()` or equivalent instead.

Comment: @101010: The use of `std::string` is fine for manipulating data in memory, but if you put a `std::string` in a struct, you can no longer write that struct as-is to a file, or read it back.  You have to serialize the data into a flat format instead. That is more work. Using a fixed array allows for direct file I/O.

Comment: @JozemiteApps Well if you're careful there's nothing wrong. The problem is that using `char` arrays and their C facilities could cause buffer overflows. Using `std::string` is the recommend way to store and manipulate strings, unless you're programming in a very strict environment in terms of hardware resources.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes that's true. Nevertheless, I believe it worths the trouble.

Comment: Thanks; switched to strncopy instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use strcpy

```
strcpy(citizen.name, "Some name") ;
```

Use of std::string would simplyfy code but would make loading/saving to file more difficult since std::ostream.write would not be a bit more complex

Answer (score 1):

Try using strcpy or memcpy with the appropriate casts.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761591/error-in-assigning-a-const-character-to-an-unsigned-char-array-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

As you have a char array, you can't just assign values with =. You should use either `strcpy()` or better, [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a `char*` to a `char[]` array after the array has been declared.  Use `strncpy()` instead to copy the content of the `char*` data into the `char[]` memory:

```
strncpy(citizen.name, "Some name", NAME_SIZE);
```