# Why does calling sbrk(0) twice give a different value?

Tags: c, memory, sbrk, brk

I'm trying to understand the `sbrk()` function.

From what I know:
`sbrk(0)` returns the current address of the break and doesn't increment it.
`sbrk(size)` increments the address of the break by `size` bytes and returns the previous address of the break.

So I created something to test it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", sbrk(0)); // should return value x
    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", sbrk(0)); // should return value x
    printf("sbrk(5) = %p\n", sbrk(5)); // should return value x
    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", sbrk(0)); // should return value x + 5
}
```

So I'm expecting to see a result looking like this:

```
sbrk(0) = 0x1677000 // x value
sbrk(0) = 0x1677000 // x value
sbrk(5) = 0x1677000 // x value
sbrk(0) = 0x1677005 // x value + 5
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
sbrk(0) = 0x1677000 // x value
sbrk(0) = 0x1698000 // y value
sbrk(5) = 0x1698000 // y value
sbrk(0) = 0x1698005 // y value + 5
```

Why don't the first two calls of `sbrk(0)` return the same value?
What happens between those two calls that changes the break address?

**EDIT :**
Storing addresses in variables solves the problem:

```
int main(void)
{
    void *toto1 = sbrk(0);
    void *toto2 = sbrk(0);
    void *toto3 = sbrk(5);
    void *toto4 = sbrk(0);

    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", toto1);
    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", toto2);
    printf("sbrk(5) = %p\n", toto3);
    printf("sbrk(0) = %p\n", toto4);
}
```

Comment: `printf` might use some dynamic memory stuff. Try assigning the values to variables instead and print them at once.

Comment: I tried it just now, it doesn't change anything, the printf doesn't have an influence on that apparently.

Comment: Then please update your question with the other code as well, so no one will repeat this assumption.

Comment: You need to use *multiple* variables, and do *all* calls to `sbrk` before calling `printf`. Your updated code does basically just the same as the first and will have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe use this checklist:https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: The updated code does not eliminate the possibility I was talking about. You are still interleaving it with `printf`s

Comment: Yes, that's my bad sorry, I tried it with variables for each call and it solves the problem.
So it was basically because of the memory management done by printf ? And if so, why did it occurs only on the first 2 calls ?

Comment: You will probably need to look at your specific `printf` implementation to find out.

Comment: My *guess* is that the initialization of the standard I/O parts is done lazily. That is, the initialization is done when they are needed, and part of that initialization is allocation of the buffer for `stdout`.

Comment: Here is the argument handling code of glibc: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c

It calls `malloc()` in a few places.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your program performs the following sequence of calls:

```
sbrk()
printf()
sbrk()
printf()
...
```

The first call to `printf` calls `malloc` internally to allocate a buffer for `stdout` (`stdout` is line buffered by default, but the buffer is created on demand the first time you print to it).

That's why the second call to `sbrk` returns a different value.

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561083/1848654) is not directly related, but the error messages from valgrind expose the existence of the underlying `malloc` call hidden inside `printf`.)

Your second example performs all `sbrk` calls up front, so there are no surprises from other functions calling `malloc` behind your back.